# Received files from axios in c# mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file, file-upload, axios

I trying, searching since several hours and no success
I've a mvc/vue/quasar application where I try to upload a photo from a button
In my cshtml file

```
 <q-input type="file" ref="myFileAvatar" v-on:change="handleFileUpload()" v-model="avatar" style="display:none" accept="image/*"/>
 <q-btn round color="primary" icon="cloud_upload" @click="getAvatar" ></q-btn >
```

I send file from my js, method section

```
 getAvatar: function () {this.$refs.myFileAvatar.$el.click()},
 handleFileUpload() {
        //const files = Array.from(this.avatar).filter((file) => { return file.size < 102500 && file.type.substring(0, 6) == 'image/' });
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('ownerID', this.profildata.ownerid);
        formData.append('file', this.avatar);
        axios.post('/forms/default/uploadProfilImage', formData, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } })
            .then(function (response) {
            //TODO
        });
    }
```

And in my controler

```
 public JsonNetResult uploadProfilImage(Guid ownerID, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        resultModel resultUpload = new resultModel();
        if (this.Request.Files != null && this.Request.Files.Count == 1)//My old version with q-uploader
        {

        }
        else { resultUpload.status = resultMessage.resultValue.error; resultUpload.message = "Oups, ou sont les fichiers"; }
        return JsonNetResult.JsonNet(resultUpload);
    }
```

Problem : file is null even if in developper mode in chrome, I see file is a FileList
ownerID is good... I try several type instead of HttpPostedFileBase but nothing (execpt object give a array of string...)
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally...
It's a type of parameter problem like I thougth

```
handleFileUpload() {
        if (this.avatar[0].size < 102500 && this.avatar[0].type.substring(0, 6) == 'image/') {
            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', this.avatar[0]);//One file
            formData.append('ownerID', this.profildata.ownerid);
            let self = this
            axios.post('/forms/default/uploadProfilImage', formData, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } })
                .then(function (response) {
                    if (response.data.status == 0) { self.profildata.idFichierAvatar = response.data.model.id; } else { self.showNotifError(response.data.message); }
                    this.avatar = '';
                });
        }
        else { this.showNotifError("L'image ne répond pas aux critères");}
    }
```

and mvc side

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonNetResult uploadProfilImage(HttpPostedFileBase file,Guid ownerID )
    {
        resultModel resultUpload = new resultModel();
        if (file != null)
        {
            
        }
        else { resultUpload.status = resultMessage.resultValue.error; resultUpload.message = "Oups, ou sont les fichiers"; }
        return JsonNetResult.JsonNet(resultUpload);
    }
```

##UPDATE : Multiple##
And for multiple files
in q-input add multiple property
in server side :

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonNetResult uploadProfilImage(HttpPostedFileBase[] files,Guid ownerID )
```

And To send files from js

```
handleFile() {
        let formData = new FormData();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.newfiles.length; i++) {
            let fichier = this.newfiles[i];
            formData.append('files[' + i + ']', fichier);
        }
        formData.append('ownerID', this.ownerid);

        let self = this
        axios.post('/files/joinFile/uploadFiles', formData, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } })
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response.data.status == 0) { self.files = response.data.model; } else { self.showNotifError(response.data.message); }
                this.newfiles = '';
            });
    }
```

I hope it's full for everyone who have same problem :-)